# How do I send a cookie while trying to grab a sites source?

Tags: java

I am trying to grab a site's source code using this code

```
private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return a.toString();
    }
```

When I do grab the site code this way I get an error about needing to allow cookies. Is there anyway to allow cookies in a java application just so I can grab some source code? I do have the cookie my browser uses to log me in if that helps.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

This way you would have to deal with raw request data, Go with [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) that gives you abstraction and some methods to allow to [set headers in request](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html)